# Xively call works locally but not from server

Tags: xively

I'm unable to make a read call to Xively (for a single feed) from a server.  Absolutely nothing is returned.  However, the call works without error on localhost.

Settings are as follows:

Feed: public
Key: permissions: READ, UPDATE + private access

I've tried setting the referrer to the website domain, but that was also unsuccessful.

Does Xively filter based on the origin of a request even if a referrer is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved the issue about a minute after posting this.

It was the difference between 'http' and 'https'.  'https' worked locally but the server did not support that protocol, apparently.

Comment: Do you mean HTTPS vs HTTP in the referrer URL for the secure sharing key you have created or the for the api.xively.com URL?

Comment: Is this for the PNG graphs? ...as you asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732749/hiding-api-key-on-xively-image)

Comment: Both the png graphs and a GET request for a feed.  My apologies for the poor description of the issue.

Comment: You should probably drop an email to support@xively.com with the exact URLs which are not working for you, it seems a bit of a strange issue from what you have described...

Comment: Sure thing I'll definitely do that -- I still think it might be an issue on my side, though.